# Git commit does not open Sublime in a repository

Tags: git, git-commit

I am taking the Git class on Udacity and have started getting an error when I try to do a git commit in the reflections repository.

Sublime is set as my core editor, and it has been opening when I use git commit.  But now, when I try to commit staged changes, I get this error message:

> error: cannot spawn --help: No such file or directory
>       error: unable to start editor '--help'
>       Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.

I have been able to commit changes to the same files in this repository in the past.  Git commit did open Sublime then.

I can still stage files in the repository.

I can still open Sublime Text 3 using the 'subl' command while in the reflections repository.

In other repositories, git commit still opens Sublime and I can commit normally.

I looked at the files in the .git directory in the reflections repository and this is a list of the files it contains:

```
./   
COMMIT_EDITMSG  
description  
hooks/  
info/  
objects/   
refs/ 
../  
config          
HEAD         
index   
logs/  
ORIG_HEAD
```

The .git directory in the asteroids repository (where I can still commit normally) contains these files:

```
./   
COMMIT_EDITMSG  
description  
hooks/  
info/  
objects/     
refs/
../  
config          
HEAD         
index   
logs/  
packed-refs
```

I have also searched the forums here, but similar questions all seem to be related to errors setting up the core.editor and/or subl alias, and I have not seen this particular error before.

Answer (score 1):

Run

```
git config --get core.editor
```

And see what it says. Since this seems to only affect one repo, it's most likely an errant setting in your local config. Try unsetting the editor locally (go back to your global default) to see if that clears things up:

```
git config --local --unset core.editor
```

Comment: This solved the problem.  I had somehow changed the local editor to --help.  After checking the core.editor in different directories using git config --get core.editor, I reset it in the reflections repository using git config --local --unset core.editor.

Comment: Glad to hear it @Evolver